# Implementing vtkLagrangianParticleTracker in python

Tags: python, visualization, vtk, paraview, openfoam

I am trying to understand and implement how the **vtkLagrangianParticleTracker (LPT)** works. I tried to modify the [kitchen example](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Python/Visualization/Kitchen/). Basically, replaced the **vtkStreamTracer** arguments with the **LPT** arguments. My issue is how the particle data is inputted.

I tried something like this...

```
paths = vtk.LagrangianParticleTracker()
paths.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
paths.SetSourceConnection(point.GetOutputPort())
matida = vtk.vtkLagrangianMatidaIntegrationModel()
paths.SetIntegrationModel(matida)
paths.Update()
```

The `reader` comes from the  [kitchen example](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Python/Visualization/Kitchen/) and I replaced the `line` with `point`. In the code, I am missing particle arguments. I need help with creating a particle with random specifications and inputting this data into the LPT.

Thanks for your help in advance!!

Comment: seems to have an answer on [this cross -post](https://discourse.vtk.org/t/vtklagrangianparticletracker-python-commands/6477)

Comment: Thanks! That was me. Got a quick reply there.